# ¿Por qué recibo el error "1044 - Access denied for user 'm'@'localhost' to database 'ODS_DB'"?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando importar una base de datos en phpMyadmin, es un archivo ods, y cuando la importo, me sale el error:

consulta SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `ODS_DB` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> 1044 - Access denied for user 'm'@'localhost' to database 'ODS_DB'

No sé si será por el nombre o qué.

Comment: es porque tu nivel de usuario no tiene los privilegios necesarios osbre la base ODS_DB.

Si es una base de prueba y tienes root, intenta hacerlo como tal

Comment: marxal, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Una vez que tengas 50 puntos de reputación podrás [hacer comentarios](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: A mí me pasaba el mismo problema pero la solución fue que la nueva base de datos y la del código no se llamaban igual, borrando las líneas que comprueba si existe la base de datos y sino no la crea

Comment: tengo este mismo error pero no se como solucionarlo y no pude hacer lo que dice en el post

Answer (score 4):

Parece que tu usuario de mysql 'm' no tiene privilegios para crear una base de datos nueva, prueba a acceder a phpmyadmin como usuario root

Answer (score 2):

Intenta darle permisos a tu usuario con lo siguiente

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'usuario'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

con esto le das permisos al usuario y refrescas todos los permisos

Comment: Ese era mi problema, no había dado privilegios al usuario sobre la base de datos. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Borra esa linea y la siguiente linea que dice Use 'ODS_DB' cambialo por la base de datos que ya tengas creada en phpmyadmin, fijate en los prefijos de las tablas y si ya tienes las mismas tablas y no las quieres perder cambia todos los prefijos en tu script.

Answer (score 0):

Yo encontré la solución aquí

[https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/es/articles/221615208-Soluci%C3%B3n-de-problemas-de-errores-de-importaci%C3%B3n-de-bases-de-datos#:~:text=ERROR%201044&text=Este%20mensaje%20de%20error%20indica,MySQL%20que%20est%C3%A1%20siendo%20importado](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/es/articles/221615208-Soluci%C3%B3n-de-problemas-de-errores-de-importaci%C3%B3n-de-bases-de-datos#:%7E:text=ERROR%201044&text=Este%20mensaje%20de%20error%20indica,MySQL%20que%20est%C3%A1%20siendo%20importado).

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).